# Getting fatal error after compiling python script containing SimpleCV module

Tags: python-2.7, simplecv

I wrote a program that takes the picture from my webcam and also takes the screenshot of my screen and send them to my email. I used SimpleCV module to take the picture from webcam and pyautogui module to take the screenshot of my screen. I compiled my script using pyinstaller using command **pyinstaller -w -i myicon.ico web_shot.py -F** I ran the compiled exe file to my another computer but gave me **fatal error failed to execute web_shot**. Later I removed everything related with pyautogui (**thinking that it is the thing that is throwing the error**). I again compiled the rest of my script and again got the same error. Again I thought problem might be in SimpleCV module so I removed everything related with SimpleCV module and again compiled the rest of script using pyinstaller. This time I didn't get any error.  It worked fine.

I have written all my codes in python 2.7.15 (32-bit) because SimpleCV module doesn't support python 3+.

I think pyinstaller is unable to recognize or compile the SimpleCV module. I tried other compiling script like py2exe, cx_Freeze but could not get success.

**How can I compile my this script without getting fatal error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fatal error is caused due to missing of **opencv_ffmpeg341.dll** in your directory where you have **.exe** file is.

Solve it by copying **opencv_ffmpeg341.dll** from **C:\"your python installed path"\Lib\site-packages\cv2** to the same path where your executable **(.exe)** is.